# Jquery doesn't hide DIV with variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Building a JQUERY menu based on HOVER. When users mouse over ID TYPO it extracts the number of the TYPO ID and pass it to the ID of CAT. So if I hover DIV ID = TYPO2 it should display DIV ID=CAT2. This works fine except that I want to hide the CAT when mouse leaves and it doesn't work unless I declare again and repeat the catId variable in HOVER OUT.
IS there another more efficient way the to this ?

Thanks in advance

CODE :

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#cat1, #cat2, #cat3").hide();

$("#typo1, #typo2, #typo3").hover(function(){
var catId = $(this).attr('id');
catId = catId.substring(4,5);
$("#cat"+catId).show("fast")
},
function(){
var catId = $(this).attr('id');
catId = catId.substring(4,5);
$("#cat"+catId).hide("fast")
});
 }); 
</script>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="typo">
        <div id="typo1" class="typo">Typo1</div>
        <div id="typo2" class="typo">Typo2</div>
        <div id="typo3" class="typo">Typo3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="cat">
        <div id="cat1">CAT1</div>
        <div id="cat2">CAT2</div>
        <div id="cat3">CAT3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there always a 1:1 relationship between `typo` and `cat` divs?

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes and data-attributes it makes things much easier:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $(".cat").hide();

        $(".typo").hover(function(){
            var catId = $(this).data('id');
            $(".cat[data-id='"+catId+"']").show("fast")
        },
        function(){
            var catId = $(this).data('id');
            $(".cat[data-id='"+catId+"']").hide("fast")
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="container">
    <div id="typo">
        <div data-id="1" class="typo">Typo1</div>
        <div data-id="2" class="typo">Typo2</div>
        <div data-id="3" class="typo">Typo3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="cat">
        <div data-id="1" class="cat">CAT1</div>
        <div data-id="2" class="cat">CAT2</div>
        <div data-id="3" class="cat">CAT3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also get rid of the IDs altogether now (if not needed).